# How to use arrays in Unix sh shell?

Tags: arrays, shell, unix

I want use an array in my shell script `test.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
index=100345
NAME[0]="Zara"
NAME[$index]="Qadir"
echo "First Index:" ${NAME[0]}
echo "Second Index:" ${NAME[$index]}
```

but when execute it by `sh test.sh`:

```
NAME[0]=Zara: not found
NAME[100345]=Qadir: not found
test.sh: ${NAME[...}: Bad substitution
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Only `bash` (bourne again shell) and `ksh` (korn shell) support array. If you are trying to run your script using the legacy `sh` (bourne shell), it will not work as it doesn't support array.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` to see what shell you are using.

Comment: @Will:  `$SHELL` shows the login shell, not necessarily the shell you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this:

```
sh test.sh
```

That runs the script under whatever is the default shell.

Instead, do this:

```
bash test.sh
```

This assures that it is bash which runs the script.

#### Example

Using your `test.sh` script, this generates errors:

```
$ sh test.sh
test.sh: 3: test.sh: NAME[0]=Zara: not found
test.sh: 4: test.sh: NAME[100345]=Qadir: not found
test.sh: 5: test.sh: Bad substitution
```

This does not:

```
$ bash test.sh
First Index: Zara
Second Index: Qadir
```

On my system, `sh` is a link to `dash` which is a fast POSIX shell **but it does not support arrays**.  To get fancy features like arrays, one must use a fancy shell like bash.

Answer (score 0):

The array is not supported by the simple terminal. Use the command bash your_Script_Name.sh. EX: I have a script file array.sh in which I am using the array. In this case, i will run this script as:

bash array.sh

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like your answer has all the same content as the existing answer. Instead of repeating content, consider upvoting an existing answer if you found it helpful. If you have something substantial to add to the post, then you may post a new answer.